# Track if user data is change

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

can you guys advise what should i do to track changes on a user data such as username  so that it is sync to other data in my database? For example with this data where a product can be associated to whoever post it and render it on the page. but if the user change name how do i sync that to the other data associated to the user such as this product so if i render it the product by will be the updated name?

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ace203e7df53d08d7b2fe31"
    },
    "product_img": [
        "http://res.cloudinary.com/d/image/"
    ],
    "user_id": "5acc162846d22c1184176258",
    "product_description": "something",
    "product_by": "John Doe"
}
```

Here is my current routes

```
router.get('/', root.index);

router.route('/product')
  .get(product.get)
  .post(product.new);

router.post('/register', checkUser, account.register);

router.post('/login', account.login);
```

Comment: What routes do you have in your express app right now? We need to see more code. You're asking a very broad question

Comment: @MaxBaldwin i have updated my question. i didn't know that the routes will be a factor sorry

Comment: You need a route that would handle updating the user's `product_by`. The view or that route, so the `get`, would probably benefit if the path was something like `/product/:productId`. The second part of that path would be a variable. That would give you a reference to the id you need to update